# What are some good online sources for data sets?

Tags: test-data

Some time ago I came across as site online who's sole purpose was the collection of various data sets, location data, district census data, or whatever sets community members were interested in maintaining.

My question is, do you know the site that I'm thinking of, or can you suggest any other sites that perform a similar service?

I'll suggest [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/), a great source for zip/postal, lat/long and lots of other geographical infomation.

Answer (score 1):

The most comprehensive dataset for music is MusicBrainz http://musicbrainz.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Search](http://search.msn.com/results.aspx?q=amazon+public+data+sets&FORM=QBHP)

Edit: I don't mean search generally, I mean to say:  Amazon is hosting a few selected public domain data sets for all to use.  You can find out what data sets they have available by searching.